# How to parse json format having no array inside it on sencha platform

Tags: json, sencha-touch-2

I am new to sencha so I have to set Data for which i am using this function component.setData( eval(WebServiceUtil.getAPIData('cartPage', 'getCartInfo'))) 
   But when I am printing values inside cartPage.html file on console then I am not getting any json data there. So Can you give any suggestion for this format
I am fetching my json data from getCartInfo.txt file

```
[  
   {  
      "data":{  
         "unitPrice":56,
         "shippingCity":"Mumbai",
         "image":null,
         "quantity":1,
         "productId":"genpr-5",
         "storePriceId":"12",
         "customerIp":null,
         "orderId":"2342",
         "trackingCode":null,
         "sessionId":"u48m6kn56k_66E4FE42F194803DB16D2692EA9DB608",
         "storeId":"STORE-13",
         "orderDetailId":null,
         "productName":null,
         "typeProduct":null,
         "totalAmount":56,
         "storeInventoryId":"5",
         "toCurrency":null,
         "inventorySensible":false,
         "name":"Samsung Galaxy",
         "customerId":"anonymous",
         "fromCurrency":null,
         "id":"EBEE13831114",
         "currencyConversionRate":0,
         "currencyCode":null
      },
      "response":"success"
   }
]
```

Comment: I have already solve this by my own by doing some modfication

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my question by my own. The modification which i have done
is WebServiceUtil.getAPIData('cartPage', 'getCartInfo')[0].data which help ferch data from json.